# Uncaught Reference Form Is Not Defined

Tags: error, varien

I have a form in my .phtml file with the following form tag:

```
<form id="coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" method="post">
```

and the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var couponForm = new VarienForm('coupon-form');
couponForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
    if (isRemove) {
        $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupon').value = "1";
    } else {
        $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupon').value = "0";
    }
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(couponForm)();
}
//]]>
</script>
```

When the user clicks the submit button, the following error gets spat out:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: couponForm is not defined
```

**UPDATE**

I checked that prototype is the first script loaded on the page. Also, tried to put the javascript in a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*code here*/ });
```

But it didn't help.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: a link to your website would help. Or post the full content of your form.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved!**

I was calling the code in HTML comments (live site and all!), so it looked like this:

```
<!--
 code here
-->
```

I was using Network Inspector to then remove the comments and work, but prototype considered the javascript to be commented anyway.

Once I removed the comments, it all works fine. By the way, even though it may not be syntax correct, the following does work:

```
return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(couponForm)();
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You should mark this as accepted. Don't leave loose ends.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use couponForm within couponForm.submit event. Instead it use "**this**" reference:

```
couponForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
    if (isRemove) {
        $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupon').value = "1";
    } else {
        $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupon').value = "0";
    }
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(this)();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shavkat, I tried that but still get the same error.